# How to handle/Convert "" in C#

Tags: c#

In C# Convert.ToInt32() and any method of Convert class can handle null values but all these method not handling "" as input. Throws an error "input string not in correct format"
Is there any way to handle/Convert "" to its specific value? like

```
Convert.ToInt32("") convert to 0
Convert.ToDecimal("") convert to 0.0
```

with out using if conditions

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of. Those methods are meant to take a number that can be parsed - an empty string is not.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The POD classes in C# have a method just for this reason:

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

You could even write an extension method to make this easier for you:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static decimal MyDecimalParse(this string val) { 
        decimal ret = decimal.Zero;
        decimal.TryParse(val, out ret);
        return ret;
    }
} // eo class extension
```

Comment: You could further improve this to pass the default value in (which itself could default to 0). This would give the OP flexibility to change the default per conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
int i;
bool b = int.TryParse("", out i);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything inherent in the frameworks that do this for you. It probably doesn't make sense for the entire community to understand "" as defaulting to 0 or 0.0 as you would want. I would recommend writing your own method that does what you specifically want.

Something to the effect of:

```
public class MyConvert
{
    public static int ToInt32(string input)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(input);
    }
}
```

I realize you don't want to do the if check but you will have to check it one way or another (either by checking .IsNullOrEmpty or .TryParse), so abstracting it into your own convert method at least means you don't have to do it every time.